# Beautifing $_GET Array URL

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to send a `GET Request` using a normal form with `checkboxes`

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <input type='checkbox' value='1' name='checkbox[]' value='1'>
    <input type='checkbox' value='2' name='checkbox[]' value='2'>
    <input type='checkbox' value='3' name='checkbox[]' value='3'>
    <button type='submit' name='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Right now, When i submit the form, I get the following URL

```
Firefox: www.domain.com/page.php?checkbox[]=1&checkbox[]=2&checkbox[]=3
Chrome: www.domain.com/page.php?checkbox%5B%5D=1&checkbox%5B%5D=2&checkbox%5B%5D=3
```

both URLs doesn't seems good for SEO and ease of use.

How can i turn the URL to something prettier and simpler like

```
www.domain.com/page.php?checkbox=1,2,3
```

Comment: Pretty URLs through `.htaccess`.

Comment: BTW your HTML is not valid as you have multiple `id` properties with the same value which completely renders the `id` property useless.

Comment: You can't (apart from intercepting via JavaScript). That's what forms do and how you defined it. There's little semantic difference between the default and your intended alternative. Ignore the "SEO" BS. Search engines are aware of forms, but do not randomly try to submit them themselves.

Comment: This is a weird question

Comment: @Script47 Possible to do that through `.htaccess`? How to do that exactly? For this specific URL

Answer (score 0):

**Jquery/javascript ajax the post.**

*Leaving out some of the JS assuming that would be more or less intuitive.*

```
$(document).on('submit','.form-class',function(e){
e.preventDefault();//stops all posts...
var checkboxes = $(this).find('input[name="checkbox"]');
if(checkboxes.length > 0)
{
  $.each(checkboxes,function(){
    //Loop through each to add to a string or array and concat with "," or explode and implode it with commas.
//Than do an ajax get/post to a url with query param of your choosing.
  });
}
});
```